# How to ignore specific string value when using pattern and patindex function in SQL Server Query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I have this query here.

```
WITH Cte_Reverse
AS (
    SELECT CASE PATINDEX('%[^0-9.- ]%', REVERSE(EmailName))
            WHEN 0
                THEN REVERSE(EmailName)
            ELSE left(REVERSE(EmailName), PATINDEX('%[^0-9.- ]%', REVERSE(EmailName)) - 1)
            END AS Platform_Campaign_ID,
            EmailName
    FROM [Arrakis].[xtemp].[Stage_SendJobs_Marketing]
    )
SELECT REVERSE(Platform_Campaign_ID) AS Platform_Campaign_ID, EmailName
FROM Cte_Reverse
WHERE REVERSE(Platform_Campaign_ID) <> '2020'
    AND REVERSE(Platform_Campaign_ID) <> ''
    AND LEN(REVERSE(Platform_Campaign_ID)) = 4;
```

It is working for the most part, below is a screenshot of the result set.

[image]

The query I posted above extracts the 4 numbers to the right out of the initial value that is set for the column I am extracting out of. But I am unable to figure out how I can also have the query ignore cases when the right most value is -v2, -v1, etc. essentially anything with -v and whatever number version it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want four digits, then one method is:

```
select substring(emailname, patindex('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', emailname), 4)
```